# creating a 'dictionary' in in bash v. 5.2

Tags: bash, dictionary

I am making a dict. called pvals_d. All prev. resources indicate, with bash version 4, this should work:

```
declare -A pvals_d
pvals_d["gt"]=1.6975e-05
pvals_d+=(["zelda"]=7.14e-05 ["hb"]=8.52e-05)
```

I have bash v. 5.2.2, so I thought this syntax would carry over?

This gives the error `./runBin.sh: line 3: declare: -A: invalid option` and, when I type, `echo ${pvals_d["gt"]}` or
`for keys in "${pvals_d[@]}"; do echo "$keys"; done`
it prints one value of: '1.6975e-05[zelda]=7.14e-05[hb]=8.52e-05'

Let me know if I should just install v. 4, if that's the best way forward...thanks!

Comment: your error seems to indicate you're running the commands in a shell script ... if this is the case, what's the shebang for the script (ie, are you sure the script is running under `bash`)?  what happens if you execute the 3x commands at the command prompt?

Comment: That's the error message you'd get from bash v3 or earlier, so I suspect the script isn't using the shell you think it is.

Comment: Put `echo $BASH_VERSION` before `declare` to know the bash version.

Comment: If your script _truly were_ running with bash 5.2, this code would be fine. It's not.

Comment: thanks guys! you were right. even though I had commented out out version of bash in /private/etc/shells and added new brew-installed bash path (and did 'sudo chpass -s <5.2path> <user>), it was still running on old one. I added this new 5.2 v shebang to the .sh file and it's working: #!/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.2/bin/bash